# How to add custom selection to gradient text?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using a custom selection in my CSS file but when I add gradient color to a text the selection hidden to whole gradient text how can I fix that ??

```css
::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ef233c;
}

.gradientText {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(238, 9, 121), rgb(255, 106, 0));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>Normal Text</h1>
<h1 class="gradientText">Gradient Text</h1>
```

> Note: in Normal Text Heading the custom selection works great but in
> Gradient Text Heading the custom selection hidden the gradient style.

[Live Example on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/ExNjRpQ)

Answer (score 4):

Because you have `-webkit-text-fill-color` property in your CSS code, you have to overwrite its value in `::selection` selector as well, as it takes precedence over `color` property (no matter it comes before or after the `color` property) in Webkit browsers.

For example:

```css
::selection {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ef233c;
}

.gradientText {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(238, 9, 121), rgb(255, 106, 0));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Normal Text</h1>
<h1 class="gradientText">Gradient Text</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?

https://codepen.io/Jonig03/pen/vYyOjrW

```
::selection {
    color: white;
    background: rgb(239, 35, 60);
}

.helloWorld {
    color: transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(238, 9, 121), rgb(255, 106, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used color as transparent that's why it's hidden, Here I have changed as white

```
::selection {
color: white;
background: rgb(239, 35, 60);
}

.helloWorld {
color: white;
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(238, 9, 121), rgb(255, 106, 0));
}
```

Comment: I update my question and here is live example of what I want to fix https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/ExNjRpQ